# django dynamic update forms fields without page refresh

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have build some django form using choose field with foreign key field.

All works fine but I want to ask for this fields some things.

In my app because needed used to many users works together I need this fields(choose field)to be dynamic and update select values without user refresh page to see last table upadates.

is possible to update the values from this choose fields forms or foreign key form field  without refresh page ?

forms.py

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_2= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=mymodel_2.objects.all(),label="ΔΙΕΥΘΥΝΣΗ")
    class Meta:
        model = Mymodel
        fields = ('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_fk')
```

models.py

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=254, choices=EIDOS_PROSWPOU_CHOICES, blank=True)
    eidos = models.CharField(max_length=254,choices=EIDOS_PELATHS_CHOICES,blank=True, null=True)
    field_fk= models.ForeignKey('category', blank=True, null=True)


class category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class mymodel_2(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input  type="submit"/>
```

in the html :

```
<div class="row form-group"> <label>field_fk :</label><select name="field_fk" id="field_fk">
  <option value="" selected=""></option>

  <option value="some value 1">some value 1</option>

  <option value="some value 2">some value 2</option>

  <option value="some value 3">some value 3</option>

  <option value="some value 4">some value 4</option>

</select></div>
```

Comment: You need a front end JS framework to do that. Popular ones are [React](https://reactjs.org/) and [Angular](https://angular.io/).

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr some example to begin with that ?

Comment: You need to update the "some value 1,2,3" etc dynamically to your backend? That is what you want , right?

Comment: @indexOutOfBounds no I need to update my form values in front end without refresh page

Comment: Here's an [example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-bind-data-to-dropdownlist-and-a-html-table-with-ngfor-in-angular-4/).

Comment: @Mar Look into Ajax to implement this. If you want other users to see live changes being made, look into Async too.

Answer (score 0):

Using only Django? No.

You will need to involve JavaScript into this. Some comments mention React and even Angular, those are really good js frameworks but using any of those would be overkilling your problem.

Here is where JQuery shines.

So this is a simple guide of one of many solutions for this:

1. Write a Django view that returns the desired choices you want to show.
2. Use JQuery and write a [get request](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for getting those choices.
3. Use JQuery again and modify the DOM accordingly.

This is just one approach.